# Need help with a proof involving Markov inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

I'm reading a paper and get confused about a proof. For a series of IID observations $X_1, \dotsc, X_n$, the authors claim a Lemma:
[image]

And they have the proof going as follow:

[image]

What I can do is $P(|\bar{X}| \geq \delta_n\sqrt{n}) \leq P(\sum |X_i| \geq \delta_n{n}^{3/2}) \leq nP(|X_1| \geq \delta_n{n}^{3/2})$. But how to derive the second summand in the first inequality? Also, how to bound this term
$$
P\left(n^{-3/2} \left|\sum_{j=1}^n (X_jI_{(|X_j|\leq n^{3/2} )} - EX_jI_{(|X_j|\leq n^{3/2} )}\right| \geq \delta_n - E|X_1| / n^{1/2}\right)
$$
as shown in the second inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be the event $\bigcap_{i = 1}^n \{|X_i| \leq n^{3/2}\}$. We can write
$$\Pr(|\bar{X}| \geq \delta_n \sqrt{n}) = \Pr(\{|\bar{X}| \geq \delta_n \sqrt{n}\} \cap A) + \Pr(\{|\bar{X}| \geq \delta_n \sqrt{n}\} \cap A^c),$$ where $A^c$ denotes the complement of the event $A$. Let us evaluate the two probabilities separately. We have,
\begin{align*}
\Pr(\{|\bar{X}| \geq \delta_n \sqrt{n}\} \cap A^c) & \leq \Pr(A^c) \leq \Pr\left( \bigcup_{i = 1}^n \{|X_i| \geq n^{3/2}\} \right) \leq n \Pr(|X_1| \geq n^{3/2}).
\end{align*}
For the other term,
\begin{align*}
\Pr(\{|\bar{X}| \geq \delta_n \sqrt{n}\} \cap A) & = \Pr\left(\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^n X_i \mathbb{1}_{\{|X_i| \leq n^{3/2}\}} \right| \geq \delta_n \sqrt{n} \right) \\
& = \Pr\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\left|\sum_{i = 1}^n X_i \mathbb{1}_{\{|X_i| \leq n^{3/2}\}} - \mathbb{E}[X_i \mathbb{1}_{\{|X_i| \leq n^{3/2}\}}] + \mathbb{E}[X_i \mathbb{1}_{\{|X_i| \leq n^{3/2}\}}]\right| \geq \delta_n \right) \\
& \leq \Pr\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\left|\sum_{i = 1}^n X_i \mathbb{1}_{\{|X_i| \leq n^{3/2}\}} - \mathbb{E}[X_i \mathbb{1}_{\{|X_i| \leq n^{3/2}\}}] \right| + \frac{|\mathbb{E}[X_1 \mathbb{1}_{\{|X_1| \leq n^{3/2}\}}]|}{n^{1/2}} \geq \delta_n \right) \\
& \leq \Pr\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\left|\sum_{i = 1}^n X_i \mathbb{1}_{\{|X_i| \leq n^{3/2}\}} - \mathbb{E}[X_i \mathbb{1}_{\{|X_i| \leq n^{3/2}\}}] \right| + \frac{\mathbb{E}[|X_1|]}{n^{1/2}} \geq \delta_n \right) \\
& \leq \Pr\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\left|\sum_{i = 1}^n X_i \mathbb{1}_{\{|X_i| \leq n^{3/2}\}} - \mathbb{E}[X_i \mathbb{1}_{\{|X_i| \leq n^{3/2}\}}] \right|  \geq \delta_n -  \frac{\mathbb{E}[|X_1|]}{n^{1/2}} \right).
\end{align*}

Combining the two gives the desired result. In the third step, we have
$$n\Pr(|X_1| \geq n^{3/2}) = n\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{\{|X_1| \geq n^{3/2}\}}] \leq n\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{|X_1|}{n^{3/2}}\mathbb{1}_{\{|X_1| \geq n^{3/2}\}}\right] \leq n^{-1/2}\mathbb{E}[|X_1|\mathbb{1}_{\{|X_1| \geq n^{3/2}\}}].$$
The other term is a direct application of Chebyshev inequality.